# MongoDB count and group by from all documents

Tags: mongodb

i need to do a query in a mongodb database:

I need to get the most repeated author field in all documents, but this field its inside a array documents..

```
{ _id:'1234567', 
date:'9/27/08 3:21', 
a_name:'name', 
a_nick:'nick', 
comments: [
{
body:"aa",
email:a@a.com,
author: "Author a"
},
{
body:"bb",
email:b@b.com,
author: "Author b"
},{
body:"cc",
email:c@c.com,
author: "Author c"
}
]}
```

i think i need to use the aggregate framework but i dont have idea witch clause i can use...
Any one can helps me?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `$unwind` and `$group` operators of the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)

```
db.<collection>.aggregate( 
   { $project: { 'comments.author':1 } }, 
   { $unwind: '$comments' }, 
   { $group: {_id: '$comments.author', cnt: { $sum:1 } } }, 
   { $sort: { cnt:-1 } }, 
   { $limit:1 } 
);
```

The `$project` operator is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to start with the $unwind operator - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/ Should be fairly obvious where to go from there.